# Can't Disable Checked Checkbox

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I'm trying to wite code that disables a checkbox if the previous is not checked. When I remove the previous check it fails to remove next checkbox check. If I remove it its automatically disabled but if I don't remove it its working and it's saving POST data. How can I remove it?

Here's what I'm doing ([also on jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ucb28jnd/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.check').attr('disabled', true);
  var ids = $(".check[id]").map(function() {
    return this.id;
  }).get();
  var number = 0;
  var all = ids.sort();
  var lowest = all[number];
  $('#' + lowest).attr('disabled', false);

  $('.check').change(function() {

    if ($('#' + all[number]).is(':checked')) {

      number = number + 1;
      $('#' + all[number]).attr('disabled', false);

    } else {


      $('#' + all[number]).prop('checked', false); //That here is not doing anything dont know why.

      $('#' + all[number]).prop('disabled', true);


      number = number - 1
    }

  });

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1471219200'>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1470787200'>
```

**Code does:** When the lowest by date is not checked the next checkbox is disabled.And if you enable the lowest by date checkbox the next checkbox becomes enabled.

**The problem:**
Problem is that if you check the next checkbox and uncheck the lowest by date,the check from the second checkbox is not removed(+ not disabled)

Comment: You'll need to create a full [mcve] (in the question, using Stack Snippets, the `<>` toolbar button). `$(...).prop("checked", false)` definitely unchecks a checkbox.

Comment: I updated with the input.When the lowest by date is not checked the next checkbox is disabled.And if you enable the lowest by date checkbox the next checkbox becomes enabled.Problem is that if you check the next checkbox and uncheck the lowest by date,the check from the second checkbox is not removed(+ not disabled)

Comment: Again, it will help others help you if you put a **runnable** [mcve] in the question, using Stack Snippets.

Comment: Added JSfiddle. @T.J.Crowder

Comment: ***sigh*** Why? Why not use the **on-site runnable examples feature**? So all your code is on-site? So all your markup is on-site? So people can click the "copy to answer" button to ensure their fixes are on-site?

Comment: I've copied the fiddle into the question as a Stack Snippet for you.

Comment: Thank you.I will use it from now on.

Comment: *"When the lowest by date is not checked the next checkbox is disabled.And if you enable the lowest by date checkbox the next checkbox becomes enabled."* Throw us a bone here: Which one is which? Because your checkboxes have no labels, no names, and the IDs are numbers.

Comment: I agree, I'm interested in this question, but am unable to make sense of what is going on. Oh, I think the IDs are the dates! I really think a `radio` would make sense here.

Comment: @WilliamIsted but if OP wants to have both checked, the radio is no use

Comment: If you replace `number` by `1` in `$('#' + all[number])`, they both go unchecked. Try that. Is that how you want your checkbox to behave?

Comment: I **think** when the checkbox with the highest ID is checked, the minimum ID should be unchecked by the script and vice versa. I'm not sure if this should work with more `input`s than two though...

Comment: Do you intend to have more than 2 checkboxes?

Comment: Yes the max checkboxes that can appear are 10

Comment: When the lowest checkbox is checked then the script enabled the higher one.If you disable the lower one the script is should disable the higher too.Thats the whole idea @Chax

Comment: Any new ideas from you guys

Comment: when you mean lowest, you mean by id order or the last that have been added?

Comment: Yea by id(previous id(date)) if there are more then 2 checkboxes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some question here is what i came with:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.check').prop('disabled', true); // Disable all the checkbox prior to execution

  var ids = $('.check[id]').map(function() { // Create a sorted array of your ids
    return this.id;
  }).get().sort();

  var number = 0; // The first element, the lowest also
  var lowest = ids[number]; // The lowest, kept that just to look like your code

  $('#' + lowest).prop('disabled', false); // Enable the first checkbox

  $(document).on('change', '.check',function() { // Add checkboxes change to action even to the one that might be added later on
    var element = $(this); // the element that has been clicked
    var isChecked = element.prop('checked'); // if the element is checked
    var isDisabled = element.prop('disabled'); // if the element is disabled, unused for now, might be usefull

    if (isChecked) { // we check if we are check or unchecking the checkbox 
      number++; // increment the ids index number
      element.siblings('#' + ids[number]).prop('disabled', !isChecked); // reenable the checkbox
    } else {
      var elementIndex = ids.indexOf(element.attr('id')); // get the index of the current element in the ids array
      while (number > elementIndex) { // loop through bigger id than ours
        element.siblings('#' + ids[number]).prop('disabled', true).prop('checked', false); // disable and uncheck any bigger ids

        number--; // decrement index
      }
    }
    console.log('index: '+ number + ', id: '+ ids[number]); // keep track of which index we are in

  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="1471219200">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="1470787200">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="1470687200">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="1470587200">
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id="1470487200">
```

The problem was with the increment you made on `number` which didn't worked well on more than 2 `checkboxes'. You were removing one to`number` even though you were clicking 3 boxes lower

**edit**

Credit for [William Isted](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38982304/3229805) to remind me that the [on() function](http://api.jquery.com/on/) existed.

Comment: You beat me by 30 seconds! What are the odds?!

Comment: It happens, usually it is the opposite for me, i get beaten by mere seconds :P

Comment: In fairness, you self documented, and I didn't bother. So points for that

Comment: Actually, mine functions differently, I'm not sure which is correct though.. at all

Comment: Upload yours too see it too and i will come back in 20 minutes.I"m making dinner

Comment: @SebastianJeliazkov Does it work? Did this answer helped you?

Comment: just sit on the pc will check it and replay

Comment: @SebastianJeliazkov You know you can mark this as accepted if this answer was the one working for you.

Comment: @Chax As you understand the requirements of the question, could you attempt to edit the title of the question to make it more relevant please?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that this is what you are trying to achieve, if not, we can expand upon this answer.

```js
jQuery(function($) {

  var ids = $('.check').map(function() {
   return this.id;
  }).get();
  
  var min = Math.min(...ids);
  var max = Math.max(...ids);
  
  $( document ).on( 'change', '.check', function() {
  
    var self = $(this);
    
    if ( $(this).attr('id') == min ) {
     $( '#' + max ).prop( 'checked', self.is(':checked') ).prop( 'disabled', self.is(':checked') );
    } else if ( $(this).attr('id') == max ) {
     $( '#' + min ).prop( 'checked', self.is(':checked') ).prop( 'disabled', self.is(':checked') );
    }
  
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1471219200'>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1470787200'>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1471219201'>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1470787202'>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1471219203'>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1470787234'>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1471219225'>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1470787226'>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1471219213'>
<input type="checkbox" class="check" id='1470787210'>
```

If the `checkbox` with the highest `id` is selected; the lowest will be `checked` and `disabled`. The same applies to the lowest `id`; when `checked` the highest `id` is also `checked` and `disabled`.

Comment: When I check the second from the left it also check the 7th one.

Comment: That's the min and max ID's mirroring each other... I may have completely misinterpreted what @sebastian-jeliazkov was after

Comment: I like the way you used `min()` and `max()` though, very clever. I thought about doing the same, but by sorting them, i'm sure to get the lowest at the first position, and i didn't need the max.

Comment: Pretty smart to use `on` instead of `change`, that way if OP want to add more `checkbox` later, he can. You don't mind if i add that to my answer?

Comment: Go for it. I wonder if either of our questions are what OP was trying to achieve :P